# Get the count of not null values before the cell

Tags: excel

As shown in the image in Col2 I need to get the count of not null values in the Col1 before the cell.
For cell B2 there is only one value A hence 1.
For cell B4 it should be 2 as there are 2 values A & C.
Same way for B5, 3 (A,C,D)

Data:

```
   A        B
1 Col1      Col2
2 A         1
3
4 C         2
5 D         3
6 
7 F         4
```

I have tried:

```
B1 Cell = COUNTA(A2:A2)
B2 Cell = COUNTA(A2:A3)
B3 Cell = COUNTA(A2:A4)
```

However I cannot drag this formula as it will change the cell reference.
Can anyone suggest any way to get this done in a single formula which can be applied to all the cells through out the column.[image]

Comment: I used this =COUNTA($A:$2,A2). It servers the purpose. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(A2<>"",COUNTA($A$2:A2),"")
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you so much.